# Understanding a claim made by NIST SP 800-22 on the possibility of calculating $\beta$, the probability of error type 2 in a hypothesis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, random-generation, type-i-and-ii-errors

[NIST SP 800-22](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-22r1a.pdf) on page 1-4 (that's page 16 of the PDF) states the following.  Pay attention to the bold passages.  (Emphasis are mine.)

> One of the primary goals of the following tests is to minimize the
> probability of a Type II error, i.e., to minimize the probability of
> accepting a sequence being produced by a generator as good when the
> generator was actually bad. **The probabilities α and β are related to
> each other and to the size n of the tested sequence in such a way that
> if two of them are specified, the third value is automatically
> determined**. Practitioners usually select a sample size n and a value
> for α (the probability of a Type I error – the level of significance).
> Then a critical point for a given statistic is selected that **will
> produce the smallest β** (the probability of a Type II error). That is,
> a suitable sample size is selected along with an acceptable
> probability of deciding that a bad generator has produced the sequence
> when it really is random. Then the cutoff point for acceptability is
> chosen such that the probability of falsely accepting a sequence as
> random has the smallest possible value.

Here's what I say.  In particular, in the context of random number generation, if the null hypothesis is false --- that is, if the generator is a bad one ---, there is an infinite number of possibilities for it not being random, so we don't know exactly what distribution of probability to use, so we can't calculate $\beta$.

Now, look at page 16 of the PDF again.  It says precisely what I just said:

> The probability of a Type II error is denoted as β. For the test, β is
> the probability that the test will indicate that the sequence is
> random when it is not; that is, a “bad” generator produced a sequence
> that appears to have random properties. Unlike α, β is not a fixed
> value. β can take on many different values because there are an
> infinite number of ways that a data stream can be non-random, and each
> different way yields a different β. The calculation of the Type II
> error β is more difficult than the calculation of α because of the
> many possible types of non-randomness.

So how come they state the bold passages above?  Can you educate me on this?

UPDATE.  No answers after a month.

Comment: In vetting a PRNG for use in simulation or cryptology, there is no one test where failure to reject $H_0$ can give you confidence that the generator is a useful one. You have to try out the generator on many specific tasks without finding flaws for any one of them. It took years to discover that 'RANDU' was a disaster because multidim. effects. Libraries of tasks that have led to the downfall of previous generators exist,e.g.,'Die Hard'. Right now 'Mersenne twister' (used in R) seems fine for simulation, but seriously flawed for cryptology. // Maybe quantum comp. will yield true rand numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  Indeed, no finite number of tests would ever prove a RNG to be random (for most reasonable definitions of "random").  Indeed,  RANDU's “very name [...] is enough to bring dismay into the eyes and stomachs of many computer cientists! [...] [It] should never have been used.” [Knuth 1997, section 3.3.4, “the spectral test”, page 105]  In terms of batteries of test, we should look now at TestU01 and PractRand and gjrand.  Mersenne Twister is also the default PRNG in Python, PHP and many others.  (It can be totally predicted with a sample of 624 numbers.)